# d3.js (v3) enter() not working in bar chart update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart which is working fine except when an update with longer data is passed to it in the updateChart function new bars are not created although the existing bars do transition correctly.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/glassy10/0am8c25e/7/)

```
    var initialData = [
    {Date: '2017-01-01', Volume: 56},
    {Date: '2017-01-02', Volume: 98},
    {Date: '2017-01-03', Volume: 45},
    {Date: '2017-01-04', Volume: 21},
    {Date: '2017-01-05', Volume: 40}
  ];
  var updatedData = [
    {Date: '2016-12-27', Volume: 89},
    {Date: '2016-12-28', Volume: 81},
    {Date: '2016-12-29', Volume: 75},
    {Date: '2016-12-30', Volume: 160},
    {Date: '2016-12-31', Volume: 65},
    {Date: '2017-01-01', Volume: 56},
    {Date: '2017-01-02', Volume: 98},
    {Date: '2017-01-03', Volume: 120},
    {Date: '2017-01-04', Volume: 21},
    {Date: '2017-01-05', Volume: 40}
];


var bottomPadding = 20;
var leftPadding = 30;
var topPadding = 0;
var rightPadding = 40;
var width = 375 - leftPadding-rightPadding;
var height = width * .75;
var xScale,volScale; 
var xAxis,volAxis,volAxisGroup;

drawChart();

function drawChart() {

  var gData = initialData;

  var minDate = getDate(gData[0]);
  var maxDate = getDate(gData[gData.length - 1]);
  var maxVol = d3.max(gData, function (d) { return +d.Volume });

  xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .range([leftPadding, width + leftPadding]);

  volScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([height, (topPadding+10)]);

  //set up canvas
  var stockLineCht = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width + leftPadding + rightPadding)
  .attr("height", height + bottomPadding + topPadding);

  //add x-axis
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5);

  //add r-axis
  volAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(volScale)
  .orient("right")
  .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
  .ticks(5);

  volAxisGroup = stockLineCht.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (leftPadding + width) + ",0)");

  xScale.domain([minDate, maxDate]);
  volScale.domain([0, maxVol]);

  //VOLUME bars
  var y1Bars = stockLineCht.selectAll("bars")
    .data(gData)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "bar");

  y1Bars.attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(getDate(d)) - (width/(gData.length * 1.5)) ; })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return volScale(d.Volume); })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height - volScale(d.Volume); })
    .attr("width", function (d) {return width/(gData.length * 1.5);});

  volAxisGroup
    .attr("class", "r axis")
    .call(volAxis);

  stockLineCht.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
}

window.updateChart = function() {
    console.log('update called');
  var newData = updatedData;
  console.log(newData);

  var minDate = getDate(newData[0]);
  var maxDate = getDate(newData[newData.length - 1]);
  var maxVol = d3.max(newData, function (d) { return +d.Volume });

  xScale.domain([minDate, maxDate]);
  volScale.domain([0, maxVol]);

  var stockLineCht = d3.select("#chart");

  var y1Bars = stockLineCht.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(newData);

  y1Bars.enter()
  //.append("g")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("class", "bar");
  //.append("svg:rect");

  y1Bars.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(getDate(d)) - (width/(newData.length * 1.5)) ; })
  .attr("y", function (d) { return volScale(d.Volume); })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return height - volScale(d.Volume); })
  .attr("width", function (d) { return width/(newData.length * 1.5); });

  y1Bars.exit().transition().duration(750)
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("height", 0)
      .remove();

  stockLineCht.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(xAxis);

  stockLineCht.select(".r.axis") // change the r axis
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(volAxis);
}

  // helper function
  function getDate(d) {
    return new Date(d.Date);
  }
```

Comment: hmm, it looks like you are recreating the chart in the update function. This might be of help [Update d3.js data with button press](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)

Comment: I don't think I'm recreating it - in the fiddle the bars do transition to the new data it's just that new bars are not "enter"-ing to account for the extra data points

Comment: Looks like your update function is pretty much the same as your draw function except for differences like in the draw function  ` xScale = d3.time.scale().range([leftPadding, width + leftPadding]);` and in your update function you have `xScale.domain([minDate, maxDate]);`

Comment: That's where the x scale domain is set to the new data range as I want the axes to scale to the new data. This works as you can see in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a working solution. I changed a few things.

First, the bars were somehow not being correctly added to the graph. So instead we're adding it directly through the `svg` now. I don't think it was getting the correct parent element in the previous method.

```
  var y1Bars = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(newData);
```

I also changed the part where you're entering the bars so it looks more like a transition-

```
  y1Bars.enter()
    //.append("g")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return height - volScale(d.Volume);
    })
    .attr("width", (width / (newData.length * 1.5)))
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return volScale(d.Volume);
    });
```

Solution here - https://jsfiddle.net/w7eaf3o5/6/

Comment: Thanks - that's got it working. I can see that the selector I used for the bars was off & that I didn't update the attrs of the enter selection.